# ASP.NET event handler basic question

Tags: asp.net

I am confused, wanted to confirm the below statement -

We can create multiple event handle method for the same event?

I think yes, beacuse it is overloading concept? right?

Please correct my understanding or advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to an event with as many event handlers as you want. For example,

```
Button.Click += OnClick;
Button.Click += OnClick2;    
Button.Click += new EventHandler(OnClick3); // C# 1 syntax

public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // do something
}

public void OnClick2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something 2!
} 

public void OnClick3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something 3!
}
```

This is not method overloading but using the .NET event model, an implementation of the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Take a look at the **[MSDN article - Handling and Raising events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx)** for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is not overloading. Overloading is providing same method name with diff parameter types, and count, as it will help memorizing the function name.
But subscribing to an event is not overloading, as you cannot have diff parameter types, otherwise your event handler wont be eligible to get registered. And this registration is done using some datastructure like arraylist (for ex, to keep a list of registered event handlers).

Answer (score 0):

That is the point of events - an object publishes the fact it may raise a particular type of event, and subscribers hook themselves up to that event.

When the publisher fires the event, all the subscribers are notified and their specified method called.

On a laptop for example, Windows may publish a battery low event, which applications can hook themselves up to so that they adjust their performance to conserve energy.